# Lettrine loversize on a grid

Tags: grid-typesetting, lettrine

I'd like to have a dropped capital matching the uppercase height. The `lettrine` package does a pretty good job with the `loversize` option, but it misaligns with the imaginary grid.

Is there any way to redefine the `L@height` so that it automatically matches the «grid»? I mean:

1. The top of the dropped capital must visually match the uppercase line, instead of the default lowercase line;
2. The added length doesn't have to move the baselineskip

The MWE which reproduces the «misalignment»

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[thick,red]
    (current page.north east)
    rectangle (current page.south west);
    \draw[red!30!white,thin]
    (current page.south west) grid[step=\baselineskip]
    (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\lettrine[lines=4,
    loversize=.2]
    {L}{orem}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Dropped capital with loversize on a grid]

Comment: `\lettrine[lines=4,loversize=.2]{\smash{L}}{orem}`

Comment: @egreg It works! Please, post it as an answer. Is it possible as well to do it automatically (as with \DefaultLoversize)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `\smash` the letter, so it won't occupy any vertical space:

```
\lettrine[lines=4,loversize=.2]{\smash{L}}{orem}
```

The best thing to do for making this automatic is to define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\LETT}[3][]{\lettrine[lines=4,loversize=.2,#1]{\smash{#2}}{#3}}
```

so you'll input it as

```
\LETT{L}{orem}
```

The optional argument can still be used for specifying additional keys for `\lettrine`.

[image]

I'm not sure from a typographical point of view that such an overshoot is good; think to a dropped capital that's at the beginning of a page.